# How to recive post JSON request inside the Jersey Rest Framework?

Tags: rest, jersey-2.0

I am constructing a JSON request in Javascript and trying to send this data to my Rest Webservice

```
var information = {
    "name": name,
    "mobile": mobile,
    "email": email
}

  $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
         url: 'http://xxx:8080/PostEx/test/testservice',
            jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
            cache: true,
            data: information,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonp: false,
            success: function (response) {

               alert(response);
            },
            error: function (e) {
                $("#divResult").html("WebSerivce unreachable");
            }
        });
```

This is my Rest WebService

```
package com.services;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
@Path("/testservice")
public class TestService {
    @POST
    @Consumes("application/json")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public String getData(@QueryParam("toppingid") String toppingid) {
        System.out.println("The toppingid is" + toppingid);
        String toppingobj = "SomeData";
    String  response = "jsonCallback(["+toppingobj.toString()+"])";
        return response;
    }
}
```

In the browser console under the Network tab , its saying

**405 Method Not Allowed**

Comment: You can't POST using JSONP. It works only for GET requests. If you do so, you also have to have a look at the ajax request contentType. Default is 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8', which would not match your rest resource. Also you would need to implement @OPTIONS endpoint for CORS. See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ for details.